# Override rails generator to change date_select into date_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-generators

I have been trying to override the rails generator (when you run `rails generate scaffold`) to produce for a date type a `date_field` instead of `date_select` in the form (same for time and date time). The mapping is located in `railties/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb`

`def field_type
   @field_type ||= case type
     when :integer              then :number_field
     when :float, :decimal      then :text_field
     when :time                 then :time_select
     when :datetime, :timestamp then :datetime_select
     when :date                 then :date_select
     when :text                 then :text_area
     when :boolean              then :check_box
   else
     :text_field
   end
end`

I can't work out where to put the updated `generated_attribute.rb` file. I have tried in the rails app `lib/generators/generated_attribute.rb` and `lib/templates/generators/generated_attribute.rb` to no effect. I have not found any other information about overriding this file to change the behaviour.

Thanks in advance. Using rails 5.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is no automatic overriding of this file yet.
I've put mine at `lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb`
Then you can add `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb"` on top on your overriden `lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb`:

```rb
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/rails/generators/generated_attribute.rb"
require "rails/generators/erb"
require "rails/generators/resource_helpers"

module Erb # :nodoc:
  module Generators # :nodoc:
    class ScaffoldGenerator < Base # :nodoc:
```

A bit dirty, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Does your delete scaffold still work with this setup?